# Twig_Error_Syntax The function "use" does not exist yii2

Tags: twig, yii2

```
{{'<h1>Profile</h1>'}}
{{
use('yii\helpers\Html')
}}
{{ GridView.widget({
    'dataProvider': dataProvider,
        'columns':[

            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'mon_no',

       ],
})|raw}}
```

the error is

> Twig_Error_Syntax : 
>   The function "use" does not exist

Comment: You have followed the documentation like http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-template.html ?

Comment: You're using the wrong delimiters, `{{ }}` instead of `{% %}`.